# When to use & when reading an input

Tags: c, scanf

I'm quite confused regarding the `scanf()` .
When do we use `&` when we read data from the keyboard.
To my understanding, `&` is always used when you want the program to read in something.

```
Eg. scanf("%c",&varA) or  scanf("%d",&varA)
```

I also understand that when you use a pointer, you don't use `&` for `scanf()`.

What about if I want to `scanf()` something into an array? do I use a `&`?
I know that the name of an array evaluate to the address of the first element of an array, which is also something like a pointer.

Comment: You just need to provide a pointer as the argument to store the result to.  If you use a non-pointer variable, then you use `&` to get its address.  If on the other hand the pointer is passed in to the function from elsewhere, already as a pointer, then you can just use it directly without the `&`.  If you want to store to `a[i]`, you can use either `&a[i]` or `(a + i)` with identical results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters passed to `scanf` after the first one are all addresses. You need to provide the address of the variable to assign the value of the input.

That's why, when you read the value of a variable, you have to pass its address using the `&` operator.

For example,

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
```

You can also assign the variable's address address to a pointer and use that:

```
int n;
int *p = &n;
scanf("%d", p);
```

In case of arrays, the array's name is actually the base address, i.e. address of the first element. You can use that in `scanf` too:

```
int arr[4];
scanf("%d", arr); // the input value will be stored in a[0]
scanf("%d", &arr[0]); // does the exactly same thing as the statement above

scanf("%d", &arr[1]); // reads the input into a[1]
scanf("%d", a + 1); // does the same as above
```

This way is useful for reading strings without spaces from input:

```
char str[64];
scanf("%s", str);
```

Answer (score 3):

`scanf()` uses [format string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string), so to read for a particular variable one needs to see which would give the address of the variable

---

1) For a normal variable `int a`, `&` is needed, `scanf("%d", &a);`

2) For a pointer variable `int* a`, no `&` is needed, `scanf("%d", a);`

3) For an array int `a[10]`,

- While using the name only, no `&` is required, `scanf("%s", a);`
- While using for an element, `&` is required, `scanf("%d", &a[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

> What about if I want to scanf() something into an array?

It depends on what array you are interested in.

- If it's a character array, then you can use `scanf("%s", s);` without `&` operator (given `s` is the char array).
- If it's numeric array, then you will need to `scanf("%d", &a[i]);` for individual array element, thus you will need the `&` operator.